# Why not additional predefined oracle exceptions?

Tags: oracle, exception

Oracle only associates a small number of internally defined exceptions with an exception name in the sys.STANDARD package.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/07_errs.htm#i3336

I am aware the existence of hundreds of unnamed internally defined exceptions, but why don’t Oracle do the job for us?

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/toc.htm

You might assume it would be a small task to implement additional predefined exceptions? I can think of at least a handful of errors deserving their own name. Instead, we are forced to use the pragma EXCEPTION_INIT in order associate exception names with the other Oracle db errors.

Comment: What is the question? Oracle is a very business oriented company and there are many "small tasks" that could be done. Unless there is a business case they are not prioritized. You could raise a service request and ask for it, but I don't think it will get anywhere.

Comment: I think my question is clear. I am new to Oracle and I am trying to understand if there is an explicit reason why the STANDARD package remain so static when the task at hand seems so small. For instance, why not add more to STANDARD or name all run-time errors in an error package?

Comment: I don't think there is an explicit technical reason. There has simply not been a business case for spending the extra time.